# Can I visit Croatia (as non-European resident) with a Schengen visa?

Tags: visa, germany, schengen, croatia

I am doing volunteer work in Germany, and I want to go to Croatia on summer vacations. I have a Schengen visa. Is that enough for me to visit Croatia?

Comment: Please state explicitly what type of visa you have. C-Visa (single, dual, multiple entry) or some form of D-Visa/residence permit. By default, a Schengen Visa is a C-Visa (field type on the sticker) with single entry - where the answer would then be no.

Comment: This should probably be migrated to Travel. Also, I am sure we have answered this before there.

Comment: @JoErNanO Why? Travel users tend to reflexively dump such questions on expats as soon as they smell the whiff of an expatriate. This is about travelling as an expat and ought to be on-topic on both sites.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38706/which-are-the-non-schengen-countries-that-allow-entry-for-schengen-visa-holders

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of Schengen visa you have: a two-entry or multiple-entry visa would exempt you from the visa requirement in Croatia, a single-entry visa does not.

If you were a resident in the Schengen area (holding a national long-stay or “type D“ visa or a residence permit), you would also be exempted from the visa requirement in Croatia.

More details can be found on the [website of the Croatian ministry for foreign affairs](http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area - Croatia is not currently in the Schengen area, so you would need to apply for a visa in order to visit.

The good news is that they are working towards membership.

Comment: I didn’t see any reference to it on the Wikipedia page, though. If you have a link, it would be appreciated

Comment: ["All third-country nationals who are holders of valid Schengen documents, as well as national visas and residence permits of Bulgaria, Cyprus, and Romania do not require an additional (Croatian) visa for Croatia."](http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/)